# Why it is necessary to state axiom of choice for a collection of sets instead of for one set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Informally, the axiom of choice says that we *can* choose one element *out* from *any* set (if I am right).

However, I dont understand why it is needed stated for a collection of disjoint sets (so that for each set we can choose one element out)？

I think the ability to choose out element from *any* one set is enough to state the axiom. Then it should be true when the set in in a collection of set (even infinite number of sets).

Comment: The ability to select an element from a single set is *not* equivalent to the ability to select an element from each of an arbitrary collection of sets. You cannot get the latter from the former; it is strictly stronger as an axiom.

Answer (score 3):

No. You are not right. Choosing from *one* element is rooted in the rules of logic.

First, remember that we are always working inside a proof. This means that (1) the rules of inference and axioms of logic are more or less all that we have, besides our axioms, and (2) we can only do finitely many things, since proofs are finite in nature.

So choosing from one non-empty set. If $A$ is non-empty, that means that we can prove $\exists a(a\in A)$. Using **existential instantiation** we can introduce a new constant symbol $a$ and the axiom $a\in A$. This is how we chose an element of $A$.

We did not use the axiom of choice. And by induction, we can also choose from any finitely many sets.<sup>1</sup> But what happens if we want to choose from infinitely many sets? Say, from each non-empty subset of $A$? Then we introduce a function symbol, say $F$, and we say that $F(X)\in X$ for all non-empty $X\subseteq A$, or for all $X$ in our family of sets. This lets us talk about infinitely many choices in a finite space.

Sometimes, e.g. when $A=\Bbb N$, we have some additional structure on $A$ that lets us choose these elements uniformly. In the case of $\Bbb N$, this is the linear ordering which provably has a unique minimum element in every non-empty set. So we can define $F$ quite explicitly.

In other times, e.g. when $A=\Bbb R$, we have no reasonable (or unreasonable) way of defining this sort of $F$. And the axiom of choice is necessary if we want to choose an element from *every* non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$.

**To recap**: Choosing one element from one set will only use the basic rules of logic, not the axiom of choice. Choosing from infinitely many sets simultaneously requires us to have something called a *choice function*, which lets us compress infinitely many choices into a finite proof. However, it is not always the case that we can explicitly describe such a choice function. The axiom of choice states that we can always assume that a choice function exists, just by knowing that all the sets are non-empty.

(Just to clarify the terminology, "a collection of sets" really just means "a set of sets", it's just clearer to *us*, *humans*, when we use "collection of sets" and not "set of sets". But at the same time, we want to be able and choose from any set of non-empty sets.)

---

1. There is a very subtle issue here about choosing elements in the proof, and choosing inside set theory, and I will ignore it here. Not because it doesn't matter, it does, but because I find it to be more instructive to students.

Comment: Almost understand, Besides "This lets us talk about infinitely many choices in a finite space." What is the meaning of  'finite space' here? And is AoC the basis of the definition of *all* infinite operations? like infinite unions, infinite intersections, e.t.c. As we need to check  elements of infinite many sets for the infinite operations.

Comment: "finite space" means "within the proof". Choice is not the basis for infinite operations. Those have specific definitions, $\bigcup A_i=\{x\mid\exists i(x\in A_i)\}$. This is a very explicit definition, and using the axioms of set theory (choice not included), we can prove it forms a set, too. From a beginner's point of view, it is tempting to think of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ as some "limit" operation, but in reality, it's even more "low level" than just $A\cup B$.

Comment: @ AsafKaragila However, by definition, the infinite union is in fact to check if one $x$ belong to any one of $A_i$. In my understanding, two steps involved. Firstly, get elements out of those $A_i$, secondly compare $x$ with those elements, if there is an equal then $x$ is the element of union. In first step, seems that AoC is needed. As now we need in general compare $x$ with elements from infinite sets.

Comment: You are thinking about this in an algorithmic way: list the elements, go one by one... It's not like that. You have a mathematical universe. You can ask "is this thing true or false?", even if it would involve "infinite computation". Because it's not a serial computation.

Comment: I dont understand why " choose from infinitely many sets" need an additional axiom, while "check whether belong to one of infinitely many sets" dont need. There is also no theorem guarantee we can check infinite many sets. In fact, the both ask the  question "is this thing true or false when considering infinite many times"

Comment: Because choosing requires a semblance of uniqueness.

Comment: You mean the ability to choose a *fixed* one element (from each set)? @AsafKaragila

Comment: Choosing is functional. This means that you get a *fixed* element.

Comment: Get it. Thank you. @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 1):

For picking an element from a single (non-empty) set you do not need the AoC. If you have a set from which you can't pick out any elements, then by definition (and the axiom of extensionality) what you have is the empty set.

However, formally, you can only pick out elements from finitely many sets, if you do it one by one. The power of the AoC lies in the fact that it allows you to pick elements (even if the selection happens seemingly one-by-one) from any collection of (non-empty) sets, as long as the collection itself is a set.